# How to get date only difference without time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How can I find the difference between 2 dates without time.
In this code i always get the date with time and i can't check the difference

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(x); //x is string of date which i read it from a text file
DateTime today1 = DateTime.Today; //Date
DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;

if ((dt2 - dt).TotalDays < 14)
{
    w = fields[1];
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        i += 1;
    }
    dr.Close();
    if (i == 1)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This question seems to involve a few moving parts too many. What is `dt2`, why is the datareader relevant? Or is it? If you subtract two `DateTime` values that have 00:00:00 as time values, you should get the number of days between them, but if they're of different kinds (local, etc.) then you may get hours between them.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the `Date` part of `dt`

```
if ((dt2 - dt.Date).TotalDays < 14)
```

Comment: 6/5/2016 12:00:00 AM appear like this

Comment: What appear like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get difference in days on the basis of Date only with :

```
(dt2.Date - dt.Date).TotalDays
```

or

```
dt2.Date.Subtract(dt.Date).Days
```

But if you want to display Date only you can use :

```
dt.Date.ToString("d")
```

Comment: 6/5/2016 12:00:00 AM appear like this

Comment: dt.Date -> 6/5/2016 12:00:00 AM   i need only the date

Comment: you can use : `dt.Date.ToString("d")`

Comment: OP doesn't want date as string, he want only date part difference

Comment: i used this (dt2.Date - dt.Date).TotalDays   but i gets the subtract of months in(dd/MM/yyyy)

Comment: Can you add more of your code to understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only days difference than you can use

```
TimeSpan t = dt2 - dt;
double NrOfDays = Math.Round(t.TotalDays);
```

or if you want only date part difference then use this, this will remove time part from the date first and after that set both date with time `12:00:00 AM` so when you take difference then only date part differ because time part is same

```
double days = Math.Round((DateTime.ParseExact(dt2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
                        - DateTime.ParseExact(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).TotalDays);
```